# Get status of setting: "Control notifications on your lock screen"

Tags: android, notifications, settings

On Android you have the setting "Control notifications on your lock screen" under Notifications, and to back that up you have the ability to set the visibility of your notification, as explained in the [notification Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#lockscreenNotification).

My queston is then, is it possible to get the state of this setting?

The reason i would like the state of the setting is to give the user more options, if they have enabled content hiding, but not bother them if they haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. There are two constants:

```
Settings.Secure.LOCK_SCREEN_ALLOW_PRIVATE_NOTIFICATIONS = "lock_screen_allow_private_notifications"
Settings.Secure.LOCK_SCREEN_SHOW_NOTIFICATIONS = "lock_screen_show_notifications"
```

However, since these values are not part of public API, they might change in future, or might not work on all devices.

```
int show_all = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), "lock_screen_allow_private_notifications", -1); 
int noti_enabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), "lock_screen_show_notifications", -1); 

if(show_all > 0 && noti_enabled > 0){
  // Post notification
  // ...
}
```